# Как найти в бинарном дереве путь с максимальной глубиной?

Tags: поиск, бинарное-дерево, поиск-пути

Есть бинарное дерево. Известна его максимальная глубина. 
Всё, что требуется - это найти путь от корня до листа, который по длине соответствует этой глубине. То есть, определить всю последовательность узлов от корня и до этого листа.
Пожалуйста, дайте хотя бы направление, в котором нужно копать, а то уже весь мозг сломал. Имеет ли эта задача вообще простое решение?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, вам может помочь поиск в глубину [ссылка](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/topological_sort). Запоминаете в каком порядке посещали вершины. После завершения алгоритма там, где хранили порядок посещения где-то будет заветное число равное уже известной максимальной глубине. Оттуда и крутите обратно порядок посещения.